# Clicking on route and obtaining measure or distance for that clicked point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, route, identify, measurements

Is there a QGIS-equivalent of ArcMap's Identify Route Locations tool?

[image: icon for ArcMap's Identify Route Locations tool]

I do use the LRS plugin, but I don't see this functionality in that plugin.

Comment: By "measure" you mean "how far from the start of the route"?

Comment: Yes, the distance or measure from the start of the route.  This seems like a basic function, so I'm likely just missing it somewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Arcmap you don't need a separate tool or even a plugin to access this information in QGIS (at last from version 3.4, maybe in earlier version as well).

By using the "identify features" tool  you have access to all kind of geometric information in the "derived section" including closest vertex M value and interpolated M value.

[image]

Of course this work only on LineStringM geometry (or LineStringZM) with non null M value (or in other word in calibrated route).

Answer (score 1):

Place a point on a line, then use QGIS expressions to calculate the distance along the line from the line's start point to this point with this expression (replace `line` with the name of the line layer):

```
 line_locate_point( 
     array_first (
         overlay_nearest(
             'line',
             $geometry
         )
     ),
     $geometry
 )
```

This works even if the point is not exactly *on* the line, but just nearby. In this case, it automatically takes the nearest point on the line.

*The expression used here as input of a dynamic label. Output (here: 114.6 meters) corresponds to the distance of the red highlighted segment of the line:*
[image]

*This is especially handy when you have several lines and many points per line as well as when you have points that are not snapped to the line and you want to automatically get the measurement for the closest point on the line:*
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Another way around this should be calculating length of line / route layers  using field calculator such as [this](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/calculating_line_lengths.html)